# follow and unfollow like instagrm system in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have work one project and there user can follow and unfollow another user like instagram. I had done to user listing and follow and unfollow system. But when i follow more than one user, in user listing panel follow and unfollow button both show. if i follow 3 user then user listing panel 3 button show. One button is Unfollow and two button is follow shows. My view side code is below:

```
<?php foreach($latestCompany as $companyRow):?>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="home-list-pop">                         
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <img src="<?= base_url('uploads/company_logo/'.$companyRow['company_logo']);?>" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 home-list-pop-desc"> 
            <h3><?= $companyRow['company_name'];?></h3>
            <h4><?= $companyRow['company_city'].', '.$companyRow['company_country'];?></h4>     
            <div class="btn-listing">
                <?php foreach($agentNetwork as $agentNetworkRow):?>
                    <?php if($agentNetworkRow['follower_id'] == $memberId && $agentNetworkRow['following_id'] == $companyRow['member_id']):?>
                        <a href="#" class="list-btn unfollow-btn" dataid="<?= $companyRow['member_id'];?>"> Unfollow</a>
                    <?php else:?>
                        <a href="#" class="list-btn follow-btn" dataid="<?= $companyRow['member_id'];?>"> Follow</a>
                    <?php endif;?>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

My Controller code:

```
<?php
    public function index(){    
        
        $member_userdata = $this->session->userdata('isMemberLoggedIn');
        $memberId = $member_userdata['memberId'];       

        $latestCompany = $this->member_model->getLatestMember();
        $agentNetwork = $this->member_model->getAgetNetworkById($memberId);

        $this->load->view('includes/header');
        $this->load->view('index', ['latestCompany'=>$latestCompany, 'agentNetwork'=>$agentNetwork]);
        $this->load->view('includes/footer');
    }
?>
```

My Model code

```
public function getLatestMember(){
    $this->db->order_by('member_id', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('li_members', array('membership_status'=>'Y'));

    return $query->result_array();
}

public function getAgetNetworkById($memberId){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('li_agent_network', array('follower_id'=>$memberId));
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Below i provide sample image
[image]

Above image i follow both user, so i want show only unfollow button.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use the `<form>` Tag and you just need to use `$(this).closest("form").serialize();` to get closest form data and then simply use `$(".mybtn").not($this).attr("disabled", false);` to enable all button and not the button which is pressed.

**Demo Code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Stops the submit request
  $("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  //checks for the button click event
  $(".mybtn").click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this)//use as selector
    dataString = $(this).closest("form").serialize(); //get closest form only 
    console.log(dataString)

   

    $this.attr("disabled", true); //set attr disable
    //enable all button not (this)
    $(".mybtn").not($this).attr("disabled", false);
   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="form">
<button class="btn btn-success user_status mybtn" >FOLLOW</button>
 <input type="hidden" name="followId" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="1">

</form>
 
<form name="form"> 
<button class="btn btn-primary user_status mybtn" >UNFOLLOW</button>
<input type="hidden" name="followId" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="1">
</form>
```